# HPLIP cant detect USB printer with hp-setupbut printer works

Tags: drivers, usb, hp, scanner, hplip

Printer: HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125ra

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Problem: MFU works like printer but didn't work like scanner.

Installed latest HPLIP Version: 3.19.5 from developers.hp.com.

```
$ hp-setup -i

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.19.5)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

(Note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.)


--------------------------------
| SELECT CONNECTION (I/O) TYPE |
--------------------------------

  Num       Connection  Description                                               
            Type                                                                  
  --------  ----------  ----------------------------------------------------------
  0*        usb         Universal Serial Bus (USB)                                
  1         net         Network/Ethernet/Wireless (direct connection or JetDirect)

Enter number 0...1 for connection type (q=quit, enter=usb*) ? 

Using connection type: usb

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
```

XSane show error:

[image: XSane Error]

```
$ sane-find-scanner 

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [Hewlett-Packard], product=0x222a [HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125ra]) at libusb:002:007
could not open USB device 0x045e/0x0800 at 002:006: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04d9/0x0175 at 002:005: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x2812 at 002:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0024 at 002:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x046d/0xc52b at 003:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0461/0x0010 at 003:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0024 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

[image: HP Device Manager]

[image: System Printers]

[image: Additional Printer Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with install HPLIP-3.17.9

All steps answers default except: It will ask if would you like to have this installer **install the hplip specific policy/profile**. Type <kbd>y</kbd>. An I recommend answer y for all hplip's versions.

Done: Scanner and  Printer works!